# Access value of row using Django's Case/When queryset conditions

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to migrate some value in Django, I'm using the Django model's `When-Case`. My implementation is simple, it worked with static string:

```
When(
            description__in=pre_desc,
            then=Value("pre-string"),
        ),
        When(
            description__in=post_desc,
            then=Value("some-post-string"),
        )
```

This code above works. But the problem arises when I try to add something before or after to existing string:

```
pre_desc = ["a", "b", "c"]
post_desc = ["a", "b", "c"]


StoreO.objects.filter().update(
    description=Case(
        When(
            description__in=pre_desc,
            then=Value("pre-string"+description),
        ),
        When(
            description__in=post_desc,
            then=Value(description+"some-post-string"),
        ),
        default=Value("def_str")),
    )
)
```

It says, `description` is not defined. Can anyone give me some workaround?

I also tried `str(F('description')+'randomstr')` which resulted in `F('description')+'randomstr'` in the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reference a field with an [**`F`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F), or here you concatenate the string with [**`Concat`**  <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#concat):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

pre_desc = ['a', 'b', 'c']
post_desc = ['a', 'b', 'c']

StoreO.objects.all().update(
    description=Case(
        When(
            description__in=pre_desc,
            then=Concat(Value('pre-string'), 'description'),
        ),
        When(
            description__in=post_desc,
            then=Concat('description', Value('some-post-string')),
        ),
        default=Value('def_str')),
    )
)
```

Comment: how about some way to call a function there, that would be more robust, I guess

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad: you can not call a Python function, since Django translates this to an database query, and the database can not interpret Python functions, etc. Here it will translate the `Concat(..)` expression to an SQL equivalent.